# How can I get Quote data outside Magento API?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to write a script to process all the orders from my magento store. I am able to get Shipping,Billing address and customer's name but now I want the list of items they have bought which i think will be in "quote" object.

I am trying this 2 lines to get quote object but I am getting an empty array.
Please tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
$salesCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING));
foreach($salesCollection as $order)
{
   $quote_id = $order->getQuoteId();
   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);
   print_r($quote->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not in "quote" object. You can get using this sample code -

```
$order_id = 1234; //use your own order id 
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($ordered_items as $item){     
    echo $item->getName();
}
```

Now using foreach loop on `$ordered_items`, you can get item data.

Answer (score 0):

To get order item you need order item and not quote

```
$salesCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
           ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING));

foreach($salesCollection as $order){
   $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
   .... 
   $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
   foreach($items as $item){
     echo $item->getProductId();
   }
}
```